# Error C2280 / Problem with Copy Constructor while instantiating an Object in std::vector?

Tags: c++, windows, window, desktop-application, window-managers

I am currently programming my first application by following ChiliTomatoNoodle's tutorials and modify his code to my needs. While doing so and implementing a simple WindowManager class, which has the purpose to store all the window instances in a std::vector and similar things, I got following error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xmemory(758,1):
>
> error C2280: 'Window::Window(const Window &)': attempting to reference a deleted function (compiling source file src\cpp\WindowManager.cpp)

The Problem seems to lie in the `addWindow` function, where the window is instantiated and stored in `std::vector<Window> Wnd`:

```
void WindowManager::addWindow(unsigned short x, unsigned short y, unsigned short width, unsigned short height, const char* name, Window::WindowClass& windowClass, DWORD style) {

    this->Wnd.emplace_back(Window(name, x, y, width, height, windowClass, style, this->IdGenNum++));
}
```

I already changed `push_back` to `emplace_back` to maybe avoid copying (?), but it didn't solve the problem.

Then there's also a getter (that seems to be fine and not copying anything):

```
Window& WindowManager::getWindow(const unsigned short id) {

    for (Window &element : this->Wnd) {

        if (element.Id == id) {

            return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Window` class header:

```
class Window {

private:    // Friends

    friend class WindowManager;

public:     // Nested Classes

    class WindowClass {

        ...
    };

private:    // Variables and Instances

    unsigned short Id;    // Received by WindowManager on Creation

    const char* Name;

    HWND Handle;

    ...

public:     // Constructors and Deconstructors

    Window(const Window&) = delete;

    Window(
        
        const char* name,
        unsigned short x, 
        unsigned short y, 
        unsigned short width, 
        unsigned short height,  
        WindowClass& windowClass, 
        DWORD style,
        unsigned short id
    );

    ~Window();


private:    // Functions

    ...

public:     // Operators

    Window& operator=(const Window&) = delete;
};
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for all the answers and comments pointing out that the arguments have to be passed directly to the `emplace_back` method. As it turned out, the vector still copied the object (no clue why..), but I could fix this by using `std::list` instead, which doesn't have this behavior.

Comment: Why `this->Wnd.emplace_back(Window(name, x, y, width, height, windowClass, style, this->IdGenNum++));` instead of `this->Wnd.emplace_back(name, x, y, width, height, windowClass, style, this->IdGenNum++);`?

Comment: Because I thought it's the way to do this. ^^' I think it's clearer to read and not writing `Window` seems to not solve anything either? Thanks anyway!

Comment: `emplace_back()` constructs the vector element type using the parameters you provide. By specifying `Window(...)` as a parameter, you are constructing a temp `Window()` object first, and then `emplace_back()` tries to constructor another `Window` inside the vector using the `Window`'s copy constructor, which has been `delete`d. By omitting the `Window(...)`, only 1 `Window` is constructed, inside the vector, using the `name`, `x`, `y`, etc variables directly as parameters to that constructor.

Comment: @Splize "_I think it's clearer to read_" But then, `emplace_back` doesn't accomplish it's intention: creating the object in a vector, opposed to copying it, as `push_back` does. Due to the fact, that it forwards its arguments, to the constructor of `Window`, and if it receives a single argument of type `Window const&`, the only constructor matching such signature is copy constructor. "_seems to not solve anything either_" If it's the case, the problem is not in the `emplace_back` call. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: `push_back()` doesn't have to copy, though.  It can move instead. It is overloaded in C++11 and later to accept an rvalue, so you could do this: `this->Wnd.push_back(Window(...));` Of course, it would help if `Window` had a move constructor defined, though.

Comment: Ok, you were right, this seems to have been a major issue, but the error is still there, which leaves me completely clueless. As soon as the `addWindow` function is erased, everything compiles fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line creates a temporary Window that will be moved (if there's a move constructor) or copied (if there's a copy constructor) to the `vector` - but your `Window` lacks both:

```
this->Wnd.emplace_back(Window(name, x, y, width, height, windowClass, style,
                              this->IdGenNum++));
```

With `emplace_back` you don't need to create a temporary since the argument you give to `emplace_back` are perfect forwarded to the constructor of `Window`, so there will be no unnecessary move or copy being made:

```
this->Wnd.emplace_back(name, x, y, width, height, windowClass, style, this->IdGenNum++);
```

Although this should be enough to solve this immediate problem, your `Window` class looks like it should support moving but not necessarily copying.

Answer (score 1):

The `Window` copy constructor is declared with `delete`, but when you pass an existing `Window` object into `emplace_back()`, the implementation of `emplace_back()` will attempt to use its arguments to construct another `Window` object in-place. The only way it can do this is by trying to use the deleted copy constructor.

You could either declare a copy constructor, use `push_back()`, or even better call `emplace_back()` using the arguments for your other `Window` constructor, which will avoid a copy.